# Battling at a gym simultaneously with other players

Tags: pokemon-go

It's tough to find a comprehensive guide on gym battling; most seem to exclude mentioning, or at the least barely cover, how fighting a gym with another person at the same time works.

**What is the process of battling a gym simultaneously with another player(s)?**

I think covering some of the following points would be great (suggestions/additions are welcome):

- Can more than two players simultaneously battle a gym?
- Can gym members of X and Y fight together against gym Z?
- Do players teaming up together have to start the battle within a window of time or simply as long as a battle is in session?
- Can you train at a gym with allies at the same time?
- In the event that you and an ally remove the prestige from an opposing faction's gym, what dictates who places a pokemon there?
- If someone is battling an allied gym, can you join the fight to defend? - Asked by [Aequitas](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/106901/aequitas)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you properly utilize gyms?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272556/how-do-you-properly-utilize-gyms)

Comment: @PrivatePansy Did you read my post and the "duplicate" post? The "duplicate" doesn't cover gym battles with multiple players

Comment: Be warned I've tried with my friend several times to fight a gym simultaneously and every time it has resulted in the 1hp glitch.

Comment: The multiple simultaneous players aspect is not covered in [How do you properly utilize gyms?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272556/how-do-you-properly-utilize-gyms) so this should not be a dupe of that question.

Comment: I'd like to add another question which I think fits: If someone is battling an allied gym, can you join the fight to defend?

Comment: @Aequitas Great question; I've added it to the list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Can more than two players simultaneously battle a gym?

Yes, <s>but not in the double battle style seen in the Gameboy/DS games. Both are battling in separate battles to reduce the prestige of the gym and thus take it down.</s>

As @Teaganator describes in his/her comment below: "You can be in the same battle instance with a teammate battling a gym. How that works it both players take damage as if they were alone, but they both deal damage at the same time."
You can also tell if you are battling with someone else because an icon will appear on the left side of the screen under your Pokemon's health that will tell you the nu

> Can gym members of X and Y fight together against gym Z?

I would assume so, only because of the way I understand battling a gym as explained above. Both are trying to reduce the prestige of the gym.

> Do players teaming up together have to start the battle within a window of 
>       time or simply as long as a battle is in session?

<s>No need to start at the same time because you aren't battling together as a unit. Just attacking the gym simultaneously.</s>

I don't know for sure, but from what I witnesses last night, as long as the second(or subsequent) person joins while the first(or previous) is battling, they will be grouped into the same battle. Now I'm not sure if starting at the same time will cause a problem and create 2 "instances" of the battle. I would hope/assume not though.

> Can you team battle at your own gym with players of the same color?

<s>I'm going to assume instead of battle you mean train. In which case yes, multiple members of the same team can train on a allied gym at the same time.</s>

This I do not know. I didn't test this last night. I encourage those in the comments to chime in and I can edit this part.

> In the event that you and an ally remove the prestige from an opposing
>       faction's gym, what dictates who places a pokemon there?

Whoever gets their Pokemon in first. If you're playing with a friend or someone on your team you might want to coordinate what you're putting in. If you think you and a mutual enemy took down the gym then you want to get a Pokemon in there ASAP to claim it.

Edit Note: Last night after defeating an enemy gym, 3 players put in 3 Pokemon immediately after taking down the gym. I wasn't aware you could do this. I thought you had to put in one, increase prestige, put in another, etc. Was this a glitch? And if not could someone explain this to me?

### In Conclusion:

<s>There is no special condition when battling as a team.</s> You are concentrating your efforts with another player to reduce the prestige of an enemy gym or raise the prestige of an allied gym faster.

**Also I was REALLY wrong initially.**

Also, thanks to users Theyna and Teaganator in the comments for being right when I was wrong.

Comment: Hey Ekmod, thank you for all the info. Let's say Blue members are attacking a Red gym, I believe you _can_ actually attack together in the same instance. I've heard about people seeing a friendly pokemon next to or opposite theirs, attacking together against the opposing pokemon within the same instance :O But that could just be BS haha

Comment: I've haven't seen this happen. I met up with someone last night and hit a few gyms, but we were never in the same "battle instance". I could be wrong though, and maybe we weren't doing it right.

Comment: You can be in the same battle instance with a teammate battling a gym. How that works it both players take damage as if they were alone, but they both deal damage at the same time.

Comment: I can confirm that if you attack a gym at the same time as someone else (the person I did it with was the same team also) you can see their Pokemon battling the same target as you on the far side of the arena. I believe that the gym still registers it as two separate battles though, ie. you cannot 'gang up' 2v1 on a Pokemon at the targeted gym even though it looks that way.

Comment: Oh boy was I wrong. I got to experience team battling last night. I'll be editing my post to reflect this. Sorry I misinformed.

Comment: From my experience you cannot train as a team. I've tried many times and it never puts us a group training battle. Against enemy teams, I believe that the additional people have to start battling before the first person had defeated the first pokemon. Every time we haven't done this it glitches out, although this may be different with updates.

Comment: `3 players put in 3 Pokemon immediately after taking down the gym.` This is because you only need 2k prestige to level up the gym, and you gain 2k prestige for putting a pokemon in the gym, [see this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/275812/106901)

Comment: The first 3 slots in a new gym are open. To add more pokemon beyond that you need to add prestige

Comment: So what @Aequitas says makes sense.  Because Lv1: 0-2k prestige, Lv2: 2-4k prestige, Lv3: 4-8k prestige.   If adding a pokemon increases prestige by 2k, then it's possible to get to 6k prestige (Lv3) from the get-go.  Because putting the first pokemon in, bumps the gym to 2k (Lv2) and opens a new space. Putting the second pokemon bumps the gym to 4k (Lv3) and opens one more space.

Answer (score 1):

Earlier today I, a member of team Mystic was attacking a gym occupied by team Valor. I was doing it simultaneously with 2 members of team Instinct. I could only see one of them on my screen, but I didn't excactly hop around to check for the other pokemon. The counter which counts how many are attacking the gym said 3. I am fairly sure they were not of the same team as me since they said so and it showed when they claimed the gym.

I can therefore conclude, based on my own observations however:

- That a gym can be attacked by more than 2 players.
- A joint attack can be done by players from different teams.

Comment: Do you remember if you were also taking damage from their attacks? I had a Jolteon suddenly join in while I was attacking a non-lightning Pokemon and my Vaporeon suddenly took a massive amount of super-effective damage.

Comment: Yes, I must have been damaged because my pokémon started at full health but was not at full health afterwards. I do not recall whether type difference bonuses were applied or not.

Answer (score 1):

My boyfriend and I (both are team valor) take over gyms together. We even battle the same person (rival) at the same time by clicking go at the same time. During the battle it will show the other person in the battle with you fighting the rival player. Now once we take over a gym we let the person with the highest cp pokémon put their pokémon in to claim the gym. After doing so, we battle ourselves to gain more prestige and level our gym.

Answer (score -1):

Teams of same and opposing can team up and fight together. You are also in the same instance. The most I have gotten together has been 3 people. Hoping to test out more but we did have Instinct & Valor teaming up on Mystic together and taking the tower out.