# Can multiple players of the same team fight their own team gym?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have 3 questions related to this:

- Can multiple players of the same team fight their own team gym in order to raise its prestige?
- If you have any experience with this, then can you also include the amount of Prestige you gained for your gym and the CP of your attacking Pokemon versus the defending Pokemon in the gym.
- What would you recommend, fighting your own team gym alone to raise it's Prestige or fight with a group (if it's possible)?

Before someone marks this as duplicate, I want to mention the question was asked as part of this one, but not answered: [Battling at a gym simultaneously with other players](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274445/battling-at-a-gym-simultaneously-with-other-players)

Comment: Your second bullet point isn't making much sense. Can you clarify, please?

Comment: What do you mean , "add the amount of Prestige you gained and the relative CP of your Pokemon versus the ones that you were fighting in the gym" how do you add CP versus the Pokemon you fight in the gym?

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I was wondering how much Prestige that the player would get for their gym. I believe I read somewhere that the Prestige you gain is higher if the attacking Pokemon has lower CP than the defending Pokemon in the gym. So I wanted to know if it was similar when there were multiple attackers.

Comment: @Riftcaster Oops, I just realized I said "add" instead what I meant was if the user answering my question could indicate the Prestige that they gained from their battle.

Comment: check [this answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/276189/106901) for some details about how much prestige is gained from training.

Comment: @Aequitas Thanks for the link! I didn't know it was a linear scaling between CP of the attacker and Prestige.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can multiple players of the same team fight their own team gym in order to raise its prestige?

Yes, however it is not like when multiple players team up to take down a gym. The training can be done simultaneously but in separate battles. Each person's training has no effect on anyone else. As if the training was being done one after the other instead of at the same time.

> If you have any experience with this, then can you also include the amount of Prestige you gained for your gym and the CP of your attacking Pokemon versus the defending Pokemon in the gym.

As is outline in [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/276189/106901); you get 500 prestige for defeating a defending Pokemon with equal CP values, 100 prestige for defeating it with a double or more Pokemon and 1000 prestige for defeating it with a Pokemon half the CP or less of the defending Pokemon. For CP values between half or double it will scale somewhere between those values.

> What would you recommend, fighting your own team gym alone to raise it's Prestige or fight with a group (if it's possible)?

It's exactly the same either way for gyms of I think level 5 or less, but above that it becomes better to do it alone. The reason for this is that with more people helping you raise the prestige, the more levels you need to increase the gym by in order to place everyone's Pokemon in the gym. For example with two people you gain prestige twice as fast but need to level it up twice us much. If a gym was level 2 and needs 2k more prestige to the next level, you will need another 2k (after adding a Pokemon) in order to place a second Pokemon in the gym. But at higher levels this will change to be considerably more prestige so it is easier to only raise it by one level instead of multiple.

That being said, higher level gyms are harder for the enemy to take down and thus can be worth the additional effort.

Comment: Ah, I can't mark 2 answers as accepted. Thanks for the link and answering all my questions.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can have multiple people fight your own team's gym just like having multiple people fight an opposing team's gym and it is always better to fight gyms in groups regardless if they are your own but it is slightly different against your own team.

Prestige gained in groups is simply the sum of the individual battles since it is not possible to have two pokemon fighting the same monster while you are against your own team. The reason why you still want to train your gyms in groups is that one person can put a high CP but weak stated pokemon such as a rattata and grind prestige by beating the rattata with a lower CP but higher stated pokemon because you gain significantly more prestige if the attacking pokemon CP is lower than the defending pokemon CP. Placing your pokemon on a gym in a specific order is also important since the lowest CP pokemon will always show up first however you want to go up against a 900 CP raticate over a 800 CP vaproeon when grinding prestige.

I've gained over 500 prestige from beating only **one** pokemon because my CP was lower than theirs. While I only gained 337 prestige from beating all **three** pokemon at the gym with a higher CP one.

Sources: Personal Experience

Comment: May wanna clarify your first point, two people cannot train in a group against a gym, they will be completely separate battles unlike when battling an enemy gym.

Comment: thanks for the comment, if there's anything still unclear feel free to suggest an edit. I'm having a hard time putting this into words.

Comment: It makes sense to me, thank you for adding the example of the Raticate and Vaporeon. I'll keep that in mind before leaving a Pokemon at a gym.