# Can certain moves damage other simultaneous attackers in Pokémon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

I saw some info at [Battling at a gym simultaneously with other players](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274445/battling-at-a-gym-simultaneously-with-other-players), but I didn't see any info about my question. I can't comment on other questions yet, so here we are.

My wife claims that my Snorlax's earthquake hurts her pokémon whenever we're battling a gym simultaneously. In the traditional pokémon games, moves like earthquake do affect allied pokémon in multi-battles, so her claim has merit. A friend claims otherwise, and I'm not finding an answer from crazy uncle Google.

Do such multi-target moves hit simultaneous battlers in Pokémon Go? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far there is no evidence that trainers attacking a gym interact directly at all. They can all do damage to the defending pokemon (allowing it to be defeated much faster), and the defending pokemon will do damage to all attackers at a constant rate independent of how many there are, but there is no indication that attackers can hurt each other.

Moves that would normally have special effects, such as status effects, in the regular series do only damage in Pokemon Go. This would imply that many other "side effects" of attacks have also been removed.

Pokemon Go has removed a lot of features that were in other Pokemon games, and I believe all the mechanics of double-battles are included in that set of removed features.

Answer (score 2):

No they don't effect other pokemon. Other than elemental varients no moves have any special effects whatsoever.

Comment: What do you mean? Your answer isn't very clear and could use an edit.

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe so, and I live in a veeeery competitive area. I'm sure that all damage goes directly to the enemy, and no one else